# SwiftUI iOS14 how to stop App clipboard notification when using Firebase

Tags: swift, firebase, swiftui, cocoapods, ios14

I recently updated my device to iOS 14 and now every time the app opens I get a notification with "AppName pasted from another devi..." I'm not doing anything myself to copy or paste the user clipboard so after some testings, I found that it happens only when I call FirebaseApp.configure() in the AppDelegate.

I'm still not sure which Firebase pod is calling this paste method but is there a way to stop this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is due to a change Apple made to let users know when an app pastes information from the pasteboard. Watch the [Build trust through better privacy](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2020/10676/) WWDC video for more details.

The Firebase team is aware of this issue and is working on a fix. See [this Github issue](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/5893) for more details.

Comment: It's simply amazing how bad DynamicLinks library is. Just stunning. I'm looking forward for a quarter when I don't have to disable it due to yet another critical issue. It's 3rd time this year.  Thanks for pointing out the ticket 

Comment: Nice, yeah I know the notification is an iOS 14 behavior, I just wasn't sure since I couldn't find anything online if the Firebase team was working on it or if I was supposed to fix something somehow. thanks 